# iPad Master-Detail View Using iPhone's Classes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, master-detail

I have an iPhone storyboard with a `UITableView` that segues to a detail view using a navigation controller. I'm trying to reuse my classes in the iPad version of the same app inside a master-detail UI.

Here's how my storyboards look to visualize what I'm doing:

[image: iPhone and iPad storyboards]

I want to reuse as much code as possible, and so far I've been successful in reusing my `PPAircraftViewController` class with its `aircraftTableView`.

**Question:** Since the iPad app already uses `PPAircraftViewController` to hold the table and detail views, how can I reuse my `PPAircraftDetailViewController` class with all its code and `IBOutlet`s?

---

*Xcode 5, targeting iOS 6 & 7, UISplitViewController not an option since all of this is embedded within a parent navigation controller.*

Comment: Why can't you use UISplitViewController?

Comment: The above screens are part of a navigation controller, and as I understand `UISplitViewController`, it has to be at the root of an application. I can't push to it. Am I mistaken?

Comment: You can have two UINavigationControllers as Master and Detail in UISplitViewController

Comment: Also, you are correct that according to Apple, the UISplitViewController should be your main Skeleton Controller of your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what I was looking for. I can't believe it took me so long to remember it, but the perfect solution for this scenario is a `UIContainerView`.

It lets me embed the `PPAircraftDetailViewController` inside its containing view controller as pictured below.

Thanks, everyone!

[image: UIContainerView]

Answer (score 0):

On the iPhone your `PPAircraftDetailViewController` gets pushed on the navigation stack by the `PPAircraftViewController`.

That makes either the one or the other visible to the user.

On the iPad, Apple provides a mechanism to show a MasterView and a DetailView side by side in a `UISplitViewController`.

In that case, the MasterViewController does not "push" the DetailViewController, but activates it through IBOutlets and Delegation.

You can have your `PPAircraftViewController` as (part of) the MasterViewController and your `PPAircraftDetailViewer` as (part of) the DetailViewController.

It will require some tweaking, but will also save you a lot of effort as sizing and rotating will be done by the SplitViewController.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue I'm having with `UISplitViewController` is that `PPAircraftViewController` (the top-level wrapper in this case) is pushed to from a parent navigation controller (the above scenario is one of many master/detail constructs; it has siblings). `UISplitViewController` cannot be a child of a navigation controller.